# box-shadow on bootstrap 3 container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, shadow

I'm building a little website using bootstrap. The base structure looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-wip/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style tpye="text/css">
        .row {
            height: 100px;
            background-color: green;
        }

        .container {
            margin-top: 50px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px black; /*THIS does not work as expected*/
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">one</div>
        <div class="row">two</div>
        <div class="row">three</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/ZDCjq/

Now I want the whole site to have a dropshadow on all 4 sides. The problem is, that the bootstrap grid makes use of negative margins and this makes the rows overlap the shadow.

Is there a way to accomplish this while leaving all bootstrap functionality intact?

EDIT:
The expected result is this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JddoL.png

EDIT:
this problem was only present until bootstrap 3 rc2.
the final bootstrap 3 makes the workaround below obsolete.

Comment: Hi there, do you mind posting an image of what you want to accomplish? Also remember that when something doesn't come with bootstrap you can really just write your own CSS.

Comment: Do you require the drop shadow to be the same width on all 4 sides?

Comment: and do you need the shadow to have a blur? Or would a solid shadow be fine?

Comment: @edsioufi: I need it to be blurred. (A solid one could be done with a border on the row-divs i think)

Comment: @sulfureous: i posted an image. I know that I can write my own css. but i don't know how to modify/overwrite bootstrap to accomplish this thing without messing up the whole grid-system.

Comment: @x_puma_x I highly recommend that you don't modify bootstrap's original files, you can simply make your own stylesheet, stick it below bootstrap and just use that stylesheet to overwrite anything that bootstrap does in one way that you would like to use in another way. This leave stock bootstrap intact and all the code working like it should but just with your code on top of it.

Comment: @sulfureous: thats what i'm doing. but can you tell me which things to overwrite to solve the problem and leave the bootstrap functionality intact?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Y93TX/2/

```
     @import url("http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-wip/css/bootstrap.min.css");

.row {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}
.container {
    margin-top: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px black;
    padding:0 15px 0 15px;
}



    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">one</div>
        <div class="row">two</div>
        <div class="row">three</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thats what the result should look like. But the problem is that i want to maintain all the flexibility that bootstrap gives me (mobile-ready). Your solution ignores bootstrap.

Comment: In bootstrap you are supposed to use `row-fluid` and `container-fluid` classes to keep the flexibility and functionality of it good with what comes stock with Bootstrap.

Comment: @sulfureous: in bootstrap 3 there are no row-fluid or container-fluid classes anymore. everything is fluid by default

Comment: I didn't know you were using 3... seems so unstable still.

Comment: the version is hidden in the topics name :-) it is already RC2 so i thought it should be usable.

Comment: @BenMun: ah. the padding seems to solve the problem. makes the whole website a little smaller but i think thats acceptable. thanks!

Comment: This breaks when you make the window smaller. You are going to need to play with the media queries as well to make sure it looks good in all sizes you are targeting. That extra padding that @BenMun added makes problems for you in smaller scales.

Comment: @sulfureous ah correct. didnt test that. now the solution is even better (edited it myself). thanks

Comment: hm. my edit seems to be deleted. this is my solution now: http://jsfiddle.net/Y93TX/3/

Answer (score 8):

Add an additional div around all container divs you want the drop shadow to encapsulate. Add the classes drop-shadow and container to the additional div. The class .container will keep the fluidity. Use the class .drop-shadow (or whatever you like) to add the box-shadow property. Then target the .drop-shadow div and negate the unwanted styles .container adds--such as left & right padding.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/SHLu4/2/

It'll be something like:

```
<div class="container drop-shadow">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">Main Area</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">Side Area</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And your CSS:

```
<style>
    .drop-shadow {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    }
    .container.drop-shadow {
        padding-left:0;
        padding-right:0;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: why is there a nested `.container` div inside another `.container` div?  How is the first one necessary?

Answer (score 4):

For those wanting the box-shadow on the `col-*` container itself and not on the `.container`, you can add another `div` just inside the `col-*` element, and add the shadow to that. This element will not have the padding, and therefor not interfere.

The first image has the `box-shadow` on the `col-*` element. Because of the 15px padding on the `col` element, the shadow is *pushed* to the outside of the `div` element rather than on the visual edges of it.

[image: box-shadow on col-* element]

```
<div class="col-md-4" style="box-shadow: 0px 2px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        {!! HTML::image('images/sampleImage.png') !!}
    </div>
</div>
```

---

The second image has a wrapper `div` with the `box-shadow` on it. This will place the `box-shadow` on the visual edges of the element.

[image: box-shadow on wrapper div]

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div id="wrapper-div" style="box-shadow: 0px 2px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            {!! HTML::image('images/sampleImage.png') !!}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way I can add a label at the bottom center of the image?

Answer (score 0):

You should give the container an id and use that in your custom css file (which should be linked after the bootstrap css):

`#container {
     box-shadow: values
}`